# different sort criteria depending on term ID

Tags: views

I'm using views for my taxonomy term page. I want to sort the nodes in some categories by title, while nodes in other categories by weight. I've been poking around the views UI but I can't figure it out. I was thinking that I probably should implement some hook or create a custom query but I don't know where to start. How do I achieve this?

Comment: why not just create different displays in views for each content type with the custom sort criteria for each?

Comment: it's not content types; it's term ids/term pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished what I wanted to do by using `hook_views_pre_build()` and `hook_views_query_alter()`

```
 /* Remove sorting by weight if viewing a category that should be alphabetized.*/
 function commerce_customizations_views_pre_build(&$view) {
   $alphabetize = array('3','58');

   if($view->name == 'taxonomy_term' && $view->current_display == 'page'
   && in_array($view->args[0], $alphabetize)) { 
    unset($view->sort['weight']);
   }
 }

 /* Sort by title if viewing a category that should be alphabetized.*/  
 function commerce_customizations_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
   $alphabetize = array('3','58');

   if($view->name == 'taxonomy_term' && $view->current_display == 'page'
      && in_array($view->args[0], $alphabetize)) {
        $query->add_orderby('node','title','ASC');
   }
 }
```